# How to call exported function from dll in C/C++?

Tags: function, dll, call, dllexport, function-address

My aim is to call some function via its address. How can I do it?

I have done the next work for such aim, but at first(1) - I've got access violation ( don't know why ) and with the second I have some problems with calling function is ASM with ESP value...

The first (the problem with access violation):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

const DWORD_PTR offset = 0x00001a90;

typedef void (__stdcall *uef)(int);

int main(void)
{
    HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Windows\\system32\\OpenAL32.dll");

    DWORD_PTR addr = (DWORD_PTR)hModule + offset;

    uef func = (uef)offset;
    func(0);

    return 0;
}
```

The second (problems at runtime with ESP value):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

typedef void (__stdcall *uef)(int);

int main(void)
{
    HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Windows\\system32\\OpenAL32.dll");
    uef obj = NULL;

    if(hModule != NULL)
    {
        obj = reinterpret_cast<uef>(GetProcAddress(hModule, "alEnable"));
    }

    if(obj != NULL)
    {
        (*obj)(0);
    }

    if(hModule != NULL)
    {
        FreeLibrary(hModule);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How could I solve this problem?

PS

And the another main question is:

**How can I dynamically calculate the function address in runtime for next calling?**

Thanks,

Best Regards!

Comment: `GetProcAddress` is *the* way to go. However, you must check that your function type definition matches that defined in the library *exactly*. Also, make sure that symbol (function) is exposed by the library (you can load the dll up in *depends.exe* and see all exported functions).

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a major issue (hence the access violation) with the hardcoded address offset (const DWORD_PTR offset = 0x00001a90). Don't do that! How can you know that the offsett will not be changed because of [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)?

Comment: Since the function is exported, just use GetProcAddress, period. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx)